# Rust Tokio TcpStream Listen and Read

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

1. So I began with the functionality to connect a `TcpStream` to an `IP:Port`. (Works)
2. From there, I created a function to be able to send messages using this connection. (Works)
3. I then tried adding the functionality to read from the socket... (not working in the same manner) - this is where I could use some help.

**Code:**

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Connection {
    stream: Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>,
    loc: usize,
}
```

```
// 1. Connect Stream to Address and Return Connection to use for later
async fn connect(loc:usize) -> Result<Connection, ConnectionError> {
        println!("Connecting");
        
        let mut socket = TcpStream::connect("IP:PORT").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;
        
        Ok( Connection {
            stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(socket)),
            loc: loc,
            }
        )
}
```

```
//2. Get stream from Arc - send message to connection - if there is an error, set to `SendError`
async fn Send(connection: Connection, string: String) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
    let mut stream = connection.stream.lock().await;
    stream.write_all(string.as_bytes()).await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::SendError(connection.loc))?;
    Ok( () )
}
```

To create the listening part from my initial setup, I tried:

1. Splitting the stream (works)
2. Create a thread to spawn (works)
3. Return the initial stream to be able to execute the Send Command (Didn't work since I can't clone/copy a Tokio Thread)

```
// 3. 
async fn connect(loc:usize) -> Result<Connection, ConnectionError> {
        println!("Connecting");
        
        let mut socket = TcpStream::connect("IP:PORT").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;

        let (mut read, mut write) = tokio::io::split(socket);

        // I only need to utilize the `read` portion of the stream at this time.
        tokio::spawn(async move {
                loop {
                        let mut buf = [0u8; 32];
                        read.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
                        println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(&buf));
                }
            });
        
        Ok( Connection {
            stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(socket)), //Error Here 
            loc: loc,
            }
        )
}
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `socket`
   --> src\main.rs:312:32
    |
299 |         let socket = TcpStream::connect("3.85.107.207:80").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;
    |             ------ move occurs because `socket` has type `tokio::net::TcpStream`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
300 |
301 |         let (mut rd, mut wr) = tokio::io::split(socket);
    |                                                 ------ value moved here
...
312 |             stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(socket)),
    |                                         ^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

**Question:**
I understand the concept of `Copy` and `Clone` not implemented for a `Tokio::TcpStream`; additionally, I know that `Tokio::TcpStream` doesn't implement the `try_clone()` method like the `std::TcpStream` does, but what workaround can I implement so I can

1. run the read portion of the stream when it connects;
2. Send messages at a later time, when I am ready to send messages?

Comment: If you `split()` into a reader and writer, why do you try to use the original `socket` again?

Comment: (New to Rust) -- How can I use the writer at a future time? I don't want to write at that exact moment - I'd like to write at a future time. As noted, I already found a way to do it prior with my #2 - I was hoping to maintain that structure. It would seem odd to only return the `WriteHalf<TcpStream>` portion instead of the entire socket connection.